# Is it possible to use BitBucket with GitEye?

Tags: git, bitbucket, collabnet, giteye

I am trying to add a repo from BitBucket to GitEye and cannot figure out how to connect the two. Has anyone else been able to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Open your BitBucket project page and copy the Repo URI.**

[image: Your BitBucket Project Page]

**2. Load up Git Eye and click clone a remote repository. Choose Clone URI.**

[image: GitEye Clone Repository]

**3. Paste the copied Repo URI from your BitBucket project page into the URI input.**

[image: Git Eye Source Git Repository]

**4. Finally you will need to update the Git Eye repository credentials with your BitBucket Credentials.**

[image]

I hope this helps! ( I just did it myself ! )

Answer (score 1):

It should be quite easy. If you have already cloned the repository you just use the option to add a local repository, otherwise you use the clone option and paste in the clone URL from Bitbucket.